# get `no method or default for coercing “character” to “factor”` when using `as`

Tags: r

In a script that I am writing I want to automate class converting. 
 Part of it is fitting data classes to existing data so I do not know what class I will need to convert to, this is why I want to use the `as` function, problem is for some reason it does not work converting from `character` to `factor`.
 
Why does this work

```
 charecters <- c("a", "b" , "g","a","g","a")
 as.factor(charecters)
[1] a b g a g a
Levels: a b g
```

but this not?

```
 as(charecters, "factor")
Error in as(charecters, "factor") : 
  no method or default for coercing “character” to “factor”
```

Comment: Just because coercing is not the same as calling a function to return a new vector. when coercing you change the class of the object "in place", when calling as.factor, you don't change the original object but get a new one.